# What is the difference between list controllers and set controllers?

Tags: apex

What is the difference between list controllers and set controllers?

Answer (score 17):

The two controllers that are available to you are:

- StandardController
- StandardSetController

> ## StandardController
>
> From the docs: A Visualforce controller is a set of instructions that specify what happens when a user interacts with the components specified in associated Visualforce markup, such as when a user clicks a button or link. Controllers also provide access to the data that should be displayed in a page, and can modify component behavior.
>
> You can find more information [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_std.htm), but basically a `StandardController` is for ONE record, i.e. if you'd like to create a new Visualforce page for a single record, you'd use a Standard Controller in  your Apex. For example:

```
public with sharing class MyController {
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }   

    // maybe this gets called from a button within your VF page
    public void doSomethingWithSingleRecord() {
        SObject record = controller.getRecord();

        record.put('Status__c', true);
        update record;
    }

}
```

> ## StandardSetController
>
> From the docs: Standard list controllers allow you to create Visualforce pages that can display or act on a set of records. Examples of existing Salesforce pages that work with a set of records include list pages, related lists, and mass action pages.
>
> You can find more information [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_std.htm), but basically Set (list) controllers are for MULTIPLE (or a list of) records, i.e. if you'd like to create a new Visualforce page for a *List* of records (or even from a selection of records on a List view), you'd use a Standard Set Controller in your Apex. For example:

```
public with sharing class MyController {
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController setController;

    public MyController(ApexPages.StandardSetController setController) {
        this.setController = setController;
    }

    //maybe this gets called from a button on your list view
    public void doSomethingWithMultipleRecords() {
        List<SObject> records = setController.getSelected();

        for(SObject record : records) {
            record.put('Status__c', true);
        }

        update records;
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help, let me know if anything is not clear!